# Converting an Activator run line to just use SBT - Play 2.5

Tags: java, batch-file, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

Using Play 2.5. I have a (Windows bat) script with an Activator run line that looks like this:

```
activator -Dhttp.port=%HTTP_PORT% -jvm-debug %DEBUG_PORT% -Dconfig.resource=%CONFIG_RESOURCE% -Ddb.default.username=%dbdefaultusername% -Ddb.default.password=%dbdefaultpassword% run
```

I want to remove activator and just rely on "sbt" to build/run my project. For some reason, I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do this. Basically it seems like sbt doesn't have a "http.port" system property. I've been able to convert this first argument by doing this:

```
"run %HTTP_PORT%"
```

My question is, how do I convert specifically that config.resource property? That's my project *.conf file. SBT is complaining about this as well.

Also, not sure if wrapping the run in quotes and following it with the HTTP.PORT is the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use `sbt run -Dhttp.port=%HTTP_PORT% (...)`?

Comment: Once `sbt` is installed, you just need to replace `activator` with `sbt`: `sbt -Dhttp.port=%HTTP_PORT% ... run`